# Text Not Showing Over SVG Rects

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have looked at every solution I could find and nothing is showing the text. When inspecting the element, the text is there in the correct position (middle of its rect) and with the correct text (.name of datum), but it does not show. How can I make it show?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wojnry60/3/

```js
const ID = "test";
const SCALE = 20;
const PAD = 50;
const MAX_X = 10;
const MAX_Y = 10;
const WIDTH = (MAX_X*SCALE) + (PAD*4);
const HEIGHT = (MAX_Y*SCALE) + (PAD*4);
var data = [
    {name:'ABC', x: 0, y: 0, w: 4, l: 8},
    {name:'DEFG', x: 4, y: 0, w: 6, l: 8},
    {name:'HIJKLMNOP', x: 0, y: 8, w: 10, l: 2}
];

var x_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, MAX_X])
    .range([0, MAX_X * SCALE]);

var y_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, MAX_Y])
    .range([0, MAX_Y * SCALE]);

var top_axis = d3.axisTop()
    .scale(x_scale)
    .ticks(MAX_X);

var left_axis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y_scale)
    .ticks(MAX_Y);

var canvas = d3.select('#' + ID)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', WIDTH)
        .attr('height', HEIGHT)
        .append('g') // <- in short, this stops transforming above elements.
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + PAD.toString() + ',' + PAD.toString() + ')')
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + PAD.toString() + ',0)')
        .call(top_axis)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (-1*PAD.toString()) + ',' + PAD.toString() + ')')
        .call(left_axis)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + PAD.toString() + ',0)');

    var rects = canvas.selectAll('rect') // returns an empty selection
        .data(data)
        .enter() // fills a placeholder for each unassigned data element
            .append('g');
    
    rects.append('rect') // fills a rect for each placeholder
        .attr("style", "outline: medium solid #07689f;")
        .attr('width', (subdata, index) => subdata.w * SCALE)
        .attr('height', (subdata, index) => subdata.l * SCALE)
        .attr("x", (subdata, index) => subdata.x * SCALE)
        .attr("y", (subdata, index) => subdata.y * SCALE)
        .attr('fill', 'red');
    
    rects.append('text')
        .attr("x", (subdata, index) => (subdata.x * SCALE) + (subdata.w * SCALE / 2))
        .attr("y", (subdata, index) => (subdata.y * SCALE) + (subdata.l * SCALE / 2))
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "14px")
        .text((subdata, index) => subdata.name);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='title' class="big">Test</div>
        <br>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` node was there, it just inherited `fill: none` from its great-grandparent `g` node. A single line fixed it:

```js
const ID = "test";
const SCALE = 20;
const PAD = 50;
const MAX_X = 10;
const MAX_Y = 10;
const WIDTH = (MAX_X*SCALE) + (PAD*4);
const HEIGHT = (MAX_Y*SCALE) + (PAD*4);
var data = [
    {name:'ABC', x: 0, y: 0, w: 4, l: 8},
    {name:'DEFG', x: 4, y: 0, w: 6, l: 8},
    {name:'HIJKLMNOP', x: 0, y: 8, w: 10, l: 2}
];

var x_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, MAX_X])
    .range([0, MAX_X * SCALE]);

var y_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, MAX_Y])
    .range([0, MAX_Y * SCALE]);

var top_axis = d3.axisTop()
    .scale(x_scale)
    .ticks(MAX_X);

var left_axis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y_scale)
    .ticks(MAX_Y);

var canvas = d3.select('#' + ID)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', WIDTH)
        .attr('height', HEIGHT)
        .append('g') // <- in short, this stops transforming above elements.
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + PAD.toString() + ',' + PAD.toString() + ')')
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + PAD.toString() + ',0)')
        .call(top_axis)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (-1*PAD.toString()) + ',' + PAD.toString() + ')')
        .call(left_axis)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + PAD.toString() + ',0)');

    var rects = canvas.selectAll('rect') // returns an empty selection
        .data(data)
        .enter() // fills a placeholder for each unassigned data element
            .append('g');
    
    rects.append('rect') // fills a rect for each placeholder
        .attr("style", "outline: medium solid #07689f;")
        .attr('width', (subdata, index) => subdata.w * SCALE)
        .attr('height', (subdata, index) => subdata.l * SCALE)
        .attr("x", (subdata, index) => subdata.x * SCALE)
        .attr("y", (subdata, index) => subdata.y * SCALE)
        .attr('fill', 'red');
    
    rects.append('text')
        .attr("x", (subdata, index) => (subdata.x * SCALE) + (subdata.w * SCALE / 2))
        .attr("y", (subdata, index) => (subdata.y * SCALE) + (subdata.l * SCALE / 2))
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .style("font-size", "14px")
        .text((subdata, index) => subdata.name);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='title' class="big">Test</div>
        <br>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aah I was trying `.style("color", "black")` instead of `.attr("fill", "black")`... Was confusing canvas text with svg text. Thanks bro!